# how to overlay a tikz picture with another

Tags: tikz-pgf

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That way both pictures are positioned next to each other.
I want the latter exactly on top of the first. Is there a builtin method to achieve this or would I have to use hspace or s.th?

The first picutre is externalized so I guess this prevents overlay/remember picture from working?!

Comment: Welcome. You can do this defining two different axis environments in one tikzpicture environment and position the graphs relative to each other

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a Minimum Working Example (MWE). To do this read and do what is indicated here: [How to make a “minimum example](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  By "on top" to you mean "vertically stacked", or do you mean "overlaid"?

Comment: You can still use [\remember picture,overlay] with the second tikzpicture, but you will lose anchor locations from the first and the origin (baseline) will be at the lower left corner (same as \includegraphics).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I actually meant "overlay" with "on top". The problem is that I have a timetable like structure that is externalized and the actual content shall overlay the timetable and not be externalized.
I guessed that would be a common problem hence created not an mwe. It seems more like a question than a problem

Comment: are there any news on this?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `[remember picture]` or `[overlay]` in this case. Simply do it in one tikzpicture: putting the code in the first picture inside a `scope` with `local bounding box=L`; and putting the code in the second picture inside a `scope` with `[shift={(L.center)}]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]  

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
\draw[violet] (0,0)--(0,3.5);
\draw[cyan,line width=2pt] (-1,0)--(4,0)--(0,3.5)--cycle;
\end{scope}

\fill (L.center) circle(.5);    

\begin{scope}[shift={(L.center)}]
\draw[red,line width=1mm] (0,0) circle(1.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can define several `axis` environments in the `tikzpicture` environment, name them and position them relative to each other using `calc` library and e.g., `at={($ (plot1.east) + (1cm,0) $)},anchor=west,`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot1,
            title=plot1,
            title style={
                at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.8)}, 
                anchor=north},
            ]
            \addplot[
            color=blue,
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0,0)
                (1,1)
            };
        \end{axis}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot2,
            title=plot2,
            title style={
                at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.8)}, 
                anchor=north},
            at={($ (plot1.east) + (1cm,0) $)},
            anchor=west,
            ]
            \addplot[
            color=red,
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0,0)
                (1,1)
            };
        \end{axis}
    
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot3,
            title=plot3,
            title style={
                at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.8)}, 
                anchor=north},
            at={($ (plot1.south) - (0,1cm) $)},
            anchor=north,
            ]
            \addplot[
            color=green,
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0,0)
                (1,1)
            };
        \end{axis}
    
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot4,
            title=plot4,
            title style={
                at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.8)}, 
                anchor=north},
            at={($ (plot3.east)+(1cm,0) $)},
            anchor=west,
            ]
            \addplot[
            color=orange,
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0,0)
                (1,1)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```