# overlay a tikz picture with another

Tags: tikz-pgf

maybe a duplicate of [how to overlay a tikz picture with another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593304/how-to-overlay-a-tikz-picture-with-another)

but there is no solution

ive been trying to overlay a tikzpicture with another
This code does not work

```
\setbox0=\vbox{\hbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ...
  \end{tizpicture}%
}}
%The width of the following picture is {\the\wd0}.
\box0
\hspace*{-\the\wd0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% ...
\end{tizpicture}%
```

maybe it is of interest that the first picture is externalized?

If i used `overlay` the whole picture is randomly cropped to a 1000th or so.

Thanks guys for your support.
Here is the mwe:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{scalefnt} 
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\tikzset{external/only named=true} % prevent unnamed graphics from externalizing - that is needed since externalizing strips annotations

{\scalefont{0.25}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[blue] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \node at (5,5) {A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
} % scalefont
{\scalefont{0.25}
    \llap{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[red] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
            \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
            \node at (-5,-5) {B};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    } % llap
} % scalefont
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see:
The pictures are not overlayed
I want to achieve that the 'cross' of both pictures is at the exact same coordinate.
In the end, only the black/blue cross would be shown (since red/black would be overlayed)
And both nodes would be shown as well (since none of them is overlayed)

Second edit:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{scalefnt} 
\begin{document}

{\scalefont{0.25}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[blue] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \node at (5,5) {A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
} % scalefont
{\scalefont{0.25}
    \llap{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \draw[red] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
            \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
            \node at (-5,-5) {B};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    } % llap
} % scalefont
\end{document}
```

overlay and remember does not work either (at least as I intend)

[image]

Edit 3: thanks AlexG

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\tikzset{external/only named=true}
\makebox[0pt][l]{
    \tikzsetnextfilename{tt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-10,-10) -- (10,10);
        \node[draw=green] at (0,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
} % makebox
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-10,-10) -- (10,10);
    \node[draw=green] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It yields

[image]

Comment: It's very hard to understand exactly what you need, since you provided only a skeleton of a code. A way to do this may be ti use `backgrounds` library and draw each `tikzpicture` on a different layer. If you could provide a more specific MWE, we should be able to help.

Comment: `\box0` first inserts, then purges the box content. The following `\wd0` returns zero. Better set box width to zero *before* inserting it, `\wd0=0pt\box0`, and remove `\hspace...`.

Comment: Maybe an idea: put the code of each picture into a \begin{scope} \end{scope} environment and move them with option [xshift=..., yshift=...].

Comment: as Alex says `\hspace*{-\the\wd0}` is `\hspace{0pt}`  but yo don't need teh low level primitives you could have used `\sbox` and `\usebox` no need to vbox/hbox etc.  or simpler just do `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\llap{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}`

Comment: Thanks for your support, I added an mwe with picture and cleared the problem hopefully (actually its not an mwe, since the scalefont is per defintion not "minimal" (also the external thing does not add to the problem)) - but both is relevant in the product version

Comment: You did not properly protect the line endings, so you will get spurious spaces that impair the result (introducing shifts). Put `%`directly after the first `\end{tikzpicture}` and after `\makebox{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exactly overlay both pictures, they should have the same bounding box coordinates.

Command

```
\useasboundingbox ... ;
```

can be used for this. It doesn't put any visible marks on the page but forces the object (here: a diagonal line) do be used for calculating the final bounding box.

In general, LaTeX-type boxes, such as `\makebox`, should be preferred over low-level box commands of the TeX layer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate!
\tikzset{external/only named=true}

\begin{document}

\tikzsetnextfilename{tt}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\tiny]
    \useasboundingbox (-5.2,-5.2) -- (5.2,5.2);
    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[blue] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
    \node at (5,5) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\tiny]
    \useasboundingbox (-5.2,-5.2) -- (5.2,5.2);
    \draw[red] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
    \node at (-5,-5) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you - that seems as easy as i expected. But your solution implies that the boundbox size is known. What would I do if I only know that both (0,0) should be at the exact same point?

Comment: it also does not work completely: if I used externalize there one picture is shifted a bit - is that a fix shift and intended? without externalize the problem does not occur - see edit

Comment: For me, outputs with and without externalisation look the same.

Comment: also if you use the example with the green boxes? one difference is that both of your pictures are externalized while only the first on mine is. - that is the reason for this. Why is this?

Comment: I edited my code to only have the first one of the pictures externalized, but still, I get them exactly overlayed.

Comment: @user239572 You must correctly protect line endings. See my comment below your question.

Comment: thats right, my bad. But do you have any idea how to calculate the bounding box automatically?

Comment: No, "automatic" means: get bbox from the objects in ***my*** `tikzpicture` environment. This is the normal procedure without `\useasboundingbox...`. Individual `tikzpicture` environments don't know each other; so cannot take into account other `tikzpicture`'s objects.

Comment: so how would i measure the bounding box exactly?

Comment: any idea on that?

Comment: There are ways to get the current bbox coordinates at the end of a tikzpicture. These would need to be written out to a textfile that is read in again on the next LaTeX run. From the values read in, the largest bbox would need to be determined that encompasses objects in all tikzpictures. It could be set with `\useasboundingbox` for all tikzpictures involved. All this is certainly possible, but would require some work, for which I don't have the resources at the moment.